# PGError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "NULL"

Tags: postgresql

Can't figure out what on earth this postgresql error is talking about.

```
PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"
LINE 1: ...at` < '2011-01-18 21:52:21.607956' OR `checked_at` IS NULL) 
                                                                 ^
: SELECT * FROM "accounts" WHERE (`checked_at` < '2011-01-18 21:52:21.607956' OR `checked_at` IS NULL)
```

Any ideas what that could be?

Comment: have you tried (`checked_at` < '2011-01-18 21:52:21.607956') OR (`checked_at` IS NULL) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backticks are your problem.

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (checked_at < '2011-01-18 21:52:21.607956' OR checked_at IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (checked_at < '2011-01-18 21:52:21.607956' OR checked_at IS NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't hit refresh before I posted― see Michael's answer, as it's the same.